# Таблица с разной шириной колонок (GridView)

Tags: android, gridview, разметка

возникла такая проблема: есть таблица(GridView) в которую из БД предаются данные и у неё все ячейки одинакового размера. Как сделать что бы первый столбец занимал половину экрана, а остальные два всё оставшееся место? Если для GridView это сделать не возможно, то какие другие таблицы можно использовать(но что бы ячейки были нажимаемыми)?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нажимаемыми в каком смысле?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну что бы при нажатии на ячейку срабатывало событие OnClick

Comment: В гридвью, вроде бы, нельзя делать разную ширину колонок. Можно в TableView и навесить на ячейки onClickListener.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а это не тоже самое что и TableLayout?

Comment: Да, конечно же. Перепуталось в голове.

Comment: @Эникейщик, слушай а как повесить событие onClick на ячейку, я пробовал но у меня оно срабатывает только при создании таблицы
            tableRow.setOnClickListener(OnClickTable(i,j,K))

Comment: Вот тут вроде есть рабочий вариант в ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579811/how-to-handle-click-event-on-each-cell-of-a-table-layout

Comment: И вот еще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987663/android-tablelayout-click-listener-for-cell-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin:

```
var COLS:Int = 3;
var tblLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.tableLayout)as TableLayout
tblLayout.removeAllViews()
var SCV=scrollView
    while(i</*количество строк*/) {
        var tableRow:TableRow = TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(     LayoutParaLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        var j:Int=0
        while(j<COLS) {
            var TV:TextView= TextView(this)
            TV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black))
            TV.setTextSize(15.toFloat())
            TV.setHeight(TV.getTextSize().toInt()*2)
            TV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grid)
            TV.setText(/*данные*/)
            if((t % 3) == 0){
                TV.setWidth((SCV.getWidth()/(1.3).toFloat()).toInt())
            }else{
                TV.setWidth((SCV.getWidth()-(SCV.getWidth()/(1.3).toFloat()).t())/2)
            }
            TV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
            TV.setTag(t)
            TV.setOnClickListener {
                var position:Int= TV.getTag() as Int//номер ячейки                
            }
            tableRow.addView(TV,j)
            t++
            j++
        }
        tblLayout.addView(tableRow,i)
        i++
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]